# Eliminating dependency on UrlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, automapper

I have an `AutoMapper` profile which currently depends on `UrlHelper` for the following mapping:

```
CreateMap<Post, OpenGraphModel>().ForMember(
    m => m.Title,
    x => x.MapFrom(p => p.Link.Title)
).ForMember(
    m => m.Description,
    x => x.MapFrom(p => p.Link.Description)
).ForMember(
    m => m.Image,
    x => x.MapFrom(p => p.Link.Picture)
).ForMember(
    m => m.Url,
    x => x.MapFrom(p => urlHelper.RouteUrl("PostShortcut", new { id = p.Id }, "http"))
);
```

This was fine up until when I wanted to reuse my `AutoMapper` profile in a context that's outside of a web request.

I can think of three solutions for this, none of which really convinces me (no particular order):

1. **Remove the `UrlHelper` dependency altogether from the mapping profile.**
   This would mean I now have to manually map the `Url` property of `OpenGraphModel`, which kind of defeats the purpose of using `AutoMapper`, in my opinion. I like my mappers being able to set all the properties I need in the destination object.
2. **Remove this mapping profile from non-web contexts, since non-web request context shouldn't be mapping to view models directly anyways.**
   In order to accomplish this, I would have to make my `IMapper` instances either transient, per web request (or thread), instead of singleton, which introduces additional overhead I do not want to introduce.
3. A third option is to not use the `IMapper` implementation on non-web request contexts (i.e. jobs), but this seems pretty much out of the question, since I'm reusing components which end up requiring me to use the mapper.

I guess having **two singleton mappers** would be the one that makes **most sense** (which choose profiles based on the context), but I don't know how I should do that, here's my AutoMapper installer in it's current form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.Mappers;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace Common
{
    internal sealed class AutoMapperInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        private readonly Type[] profileTypes;

        public AutoMapperInstaller(params Type[] profileTypes)
        {
            if (profileTypes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("profileTypes");
            }
            this.profileTypes = profileTypes;
        }

        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = profileTypes.Select(t => t.Assembly).ToList();

            foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                container.Register(
                    AllTypes
                        .FromAssembly(assembly)
                        .BasedOn(typeof (ITypeConverter<,>))
                        .WithServiceSelf()
                    );
            }

            foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                container.Register(
                    Classes
                        .FromAssembly(assembly)
                        .BasedOn<Profile>()
                        .LifestyleTransient()
                    );
            }

            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<ITypeMapFactory>()
                    .ImplementedBy<TypeMapFactory>()
                    .LifestyleTransient()
                );

            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<IConfiguration, IConfigurationProvider>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(InstanceConfigurationStore)
                    .LifestyleTransient()
                );

            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<IMappingEngine>()
                    .ImplementedBy<MappingEngine>()
                    .LifestyleTransient()
                );

            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<IMapper>()
                    .ImplementedBy<Mapper>()
                    .DynamicParameters(
                        (k, parameters) => parameters["profileTypes"] = profileTypes
                    )
                    .LifestyleSingleton()
                );
        }

        private ConfigurationStore InstanceConfigurationStore(IKernel kernel)
        {
            ITypeMapFactory typeMapFactory = kernel.Resolve<ITypeMapFactory>();
            IEnumerable<IObjectMapper> mappers = MapperRegistry.AllMappers();

            return new ConfigurationStore(typeMapFactory, mappers);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by mocking the `RequestContext` passed to `UrlHelper` in non-web request contexts.

Comment: How is your `urlHelper` "passed" to AutoMapper in a Web request?